# why is multi-select values appearing as csv and not array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl, cgi

here is my html:

```
<select id="list" name="list" size=10 multiple>
  <option value="xx">opt-1</option>
  <option value="yy">opt-2</option>
  <option value="zz">opt-3</option>
</select>
```

I am getting value of this as:

```
var list_v = $("#list").val();
```

submitting using the .post call as:

```
'&mylist='+list_v
```

in the cgi I am collecting like this(perl):

```
@list_values = $q->param('mylist');
```

I am getting all selected options as just one element in the @list_values array. I thought i should be getting all values as separate elements of the array!!!

So, for example, if anyone selects opt-1 and opt-2 I expect in @list_values  [xx yy]   (two values as two elements)

BUT, I am instead getting [xx,yy ]       (two values as one element)

Comment: formencoding doesn't submit that way, will look like: `list=xx&list=yy&list=zz`. Can use jQuery `serialize()`

Comment: `'&mylist='+list_v` does a string concatenation, so JS does a `toString()` on the `list_v` array which gives a comma-separated list (and you've specified the actual parameter name `mylist` only once at the beginning).

Comment: nnnnnn you are right. I am not using a form to submit data just an $.post ajax call so I am trying to construct the data string using &   How should I do it ? there are other elements on page (radio, input, many selects etc.) how should i get the properly formatted data string to submit using $.post call?

Comment: I dont know who felt so intelligent to downgrade the question. Since it was NOT working (serialize specific fields), THEN I had to put all inside a form and serialized the form. hope it is clear to some people now. question was put because i was trying it without using a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should make use of [.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. It would give you `list[]=xx&list[]=yy` if two options were selected. Then you no longer have to construct your data parameters string manually:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/post-collector',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('#your-form').serialize()
});
```

You can see the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/QeqvF/

Comment: thx. as i updated above. I am not using a form to submit data just an $.post ajax call so I am trying to construct the data string using & How should I do it ? there are other elements on page (radio, input, many selects etc.) how should i get the properly formatted data string to submit using $.post call?